# How to remove current page from Jquery Mobile history?

Tags: jquery-mobile, browser-history

Is there a way to remove the current page (page being navigated away from) from the Jquery Mobile history? Setting changeHash:false seems to remove the incoming page from the history.

Here is an example:

Page 1

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-id="fixedheader" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <button onclick="$.mobile.changePage('page2.html',{changeHash:false});">Page 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Page 2

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-id="fixedheader" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <button onclick="$.mobile.changePage('page3.html',{changeHash:true});">Page 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Page 3

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-id="fixedheader" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <h1>Page 3</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content"></div>
</div>
```

What I want is that when on Page 3, clicking the back button goes to Page 2 and that it is not possible to go back to Page 1.

What happens is that clicking from Page 1 to Page 2 to Page 3, on Page 3 the back button goes directly back to Page 1.

Also if I put data-add-back-btn="true" on Page 2, it shows a back button but clicking it does nothing.

Comment: Not sure why its not workig, as i usualy use clicks to go back, however try adding (data-url="page2.html") to the header and see if that works. alternatively just add ( onclick="$.mobile.changePage('page2.html',{changeHash:true});") and delete (data-add-back-btn="true")

Comment: Hard coding the button in this example to go to page 2 would make it go to page 2, but it is not a solution. In a real app, there are any number of paths between 1 and 3 and it needs to use the history to go to the correct page. This would also not be a true back but moving forward to page 2 from page 3. Also on Android people can use the back button to navigate the history and that wouldn't change.

Comment: You want to remove which page from history? Page1 or page2?

Comment: I want the flow to be clicking 1 to 2 to 3. Then when on 3, the back button goes back to 2. 2 shows no back button because 1 is not in the history.

Comment: easy option with no complications whatsoever is to add `data-ajax="false"` to _page2.html_ link in first page. e.g. `<a href="page2.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn">Page 2</a>`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using jQuery Mobile > 1.4, you can directly access and modify the history stack with `$.mobile.navigate.history.stack`

If you only want to remove Page 1 from the history when you navigate from Page 1 -> Page 2, the following code should solve your issue. This function assumes jQuery Mobile 1.4.3

```
$(document).on('pagecontainerchange', function(e, ui) {
      if ( ui.prevPage.attr('id') === 'first' && ui.toPage.attr('id')  === 'second' ) {
          var index = $.mobile.navigate.history.stack.length - 2;
          $.mobile.navigate.history.stack.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0dtuqsn/3/) which logs the state of the history stack

Comment: I'll have to check this out. Moved on to some other stuff at the moment. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Hallo! This worked finally for me, but only after I added another row: <<<<< $.mobile.navigate.history.activeIndex = $.mobile.navigate.history.stack.length-1; >>>>> don't know why, only know that without this it logs this error:  'cannot read property hash of undefined'